# Use SQL query for the rearranging the rows

Tags: sql

Below is the table given,

```
   Start_dest         End_Dest      KM
   ------------------------------------
   Varanasi           Hyderabad     50
   Delhi              Lucknow       30
   Hyderabad          Bangalore     20
   Mumbai             Goa           10
```

The result table should be,

```
   Start_dest         End_Dest      KM
   ------------------------------------
   Varanasi           Hyderabad     50
   Hyderabad          Bangalore     20*
   Delhi              Lucknow       30
   Mumbai             Goa           10
```

The data should be Varanasi-->Hyderabad-->Bangalore rowise.

What SQL query can we use for this?

Comment: What is the logic behind the desired ordering?

Comment: There are cities in the start and end destination, So in the example, we see that Varanasi and Hyderabad are two start and end cities respectively, then again Hyderabad and Bangalore are start and end cities respectively

Now we have Hyderabad as  start and end city, so it connects the three cities as such Varanasi-->Hyderabad-->Bangalore

So we need to arrange the rows on the above basis

Varanasi           Hyderabad     50

Hyderabad          Bangalore     20

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fix the ordering, you can use an expression in the `order by`:

```
order by (case start_dest when 'Varanasi' then 1
                          when 'Hyderabad' then 2
                          when 'Bangalore' then 3
                          else 4
          end)
```

Comment: Need a more efficient way to this when there are high number of data like this, We need to define the logic that would do the same for all data if this kind. Ther would be some other three cities that could be arranged in a similar way

Comment: @yashthakur . . . Huh?  This answers the question that you have asked here (or at least a reasonable interpretation of it).  If you have a different question or concern (such as performance) ask a *new* question.

Answer (score 0):

You could self-join the table to check if the current record is part of a multi-destination trip. When the start of the current record can be connected to the end of another record, you know that you have that kind of trip. Then you can use that information in the `ORDER BY` clause to order records correctly:

```
select
    t1.start_dest,
    t1.end_dest,
    t1.km
from mytable t1
left join mytable t2 on t1.start_dest = t2.end_dest
order by 
    coalesce(t2.start_dest, t1.start_dest),
    case when t2.start_dest is not null then 1 else 0 end,
    t1.start_dest
;
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xgVSa7WWX4nhGNz2bd4Snb/2)**:

```
| start_dest | end_dest  | km  |
| ---------- | --------- | --- |
| Delhi      | Lucknow   | 30  |
| Mumbai     | Goa       | 10  |
| Varanasi   | Hyderabad | 50  |
| Hyderabad  | Bangalore | 20  |
```

Note: this assume that a given trip can not be connected to more than one other trip.

Answer (score 0):

Since OP mentioned performance in a comment and this wasn't mentioned, you could create a temp table with the city (varchar) and sort order (tinyint or larger if needed) and then join to the resulting table and order by that sort order, indexing appropriately.

If the sort order is being used in multiple places, consider adding it to something like a view. You could also consider adding it to a real table that may or may not need to rebuilt using a stored procedure. There are different ways to create a reusable sort order, but I'm not sure of your specific situation.

I sometimes create a table with a sort order and then join to it to my results to get my order by and haven't hit any performance issues, but, that said, I've probably only done it with 10s of thousands of rows.

As I'm on my phone at the moment, I can't write up a query, but can later if you need an example.